# How to display printer icon

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to display a printer icon next to the share button but It doesn't show. How do I fix this ? It's built using code no storyboards. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiTLh.png)

```
 let shareButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .action, target: self, action: #selector(share(sender:)))
            let printButton = UIBarButtonItem(image:  UIImage(named: "printer"), style: .plain, target: self, action:  #selector(print(sender:)))
            navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [shareButton, printButton]
```

Comment: I don't think you should have a print button. People already know that the share icon gives you the option to print as well

Comment: It's a requirement I have to do

Answer (score 1):

Since iOS 13, you can use [SF Symbols](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/).

Usage is like this: `UIImage(systemName: "printer")`

If you support lower versions, then you have to add an image to your Asset catalog so you can use it.